# Django Template: Passing a variable from an include, into a dot notated path

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates

If I am passing in a variable to a template via an include...

`{% include "module.html" with id=someVar %}`

on the other side, how can I place it inside a dot noted path in order to call an object from a source?

```
<img class="brand-logo" src="{% static data.someVar.logo %}">
```

Answer (score 1):

I was just over thinking it - all I had to do was pass in the following:

```
{% for module in modules %}  
  {% include "module.html" with data=module %}
{% endfor %}
```

Then I can use:

```
<img class="brand-logo" src="{% static data.content.logo %}">
```